# Почасовая оплата при заказе сервиса?

Tags: веб-программирование

Добрый день!

Заказываю разработку одно сервиса, выбрал компанию исполнителя - по часовая оплата.

Возник такой вопрос, допустим исполнитель указал в ТЗ разработку определенной части сервиса - 20 часов. А по факту потратил 15 часов. Как такие моменты выявлять?

Comment: думаю никак. Вы никак не узнаете писал он или чай пил). Если цена в целом устраивает то платите и не заморачивайтесь.

Comment: камеру поставить у него и записывать его действия, а потом замерять общую длину видео где КПД > 20%))

Comment: Какое-то тут оскорбление чувств программистов, усиленно размышляющих над архитектурой проекта во время чаепития)

Comment: Можно считать, что час - это условная единица сложности реализации, которая может не соответствует фактическим часам времени работы. К тому же, например продумывание архитектуры кода или обдумывание вариантов решения проблемы не обязательно проходит за экраном монитора. Вряд ли это вообще как-то можно точно изменить.

Comment: Если бы я был таким работодателем для программистов, то если бы заказчик попросил точно показать потраченное время, то мне было бы выгоднее посадить на разработку какого нибудь новичка, с минимальной зарплатой, что бы заказчик видел, что софт действительно долго разрабатывается. Если же я на разработку поставлю сильного программера, то мне это в двойне не выгодно - заказчик заплатит меньше, ЗП выше. А то что новичок в принципе сделает кривой код, который потом будет глючить, кого это волнует.  В общем "не гнался бы поп за дешевизной"

Comment: Никак. Час здесь - некий эквивалент сделанного труда: то есть если сервис, оцененный в 20 часов сделан за 5 часов - оплата будет за 20 часов. Если компания оценивает свои сервисы в слишком много часов - то у неё уменьшается кол-во клиентов, если в слишком мало часов - падает прибыль. Математика проста.

Comment: А то что пишут про трекеры - такое есть только это не работает, из за очевидных изъянов. Можно смотреть в код с пивком 20 часов, а можно с огнём в глазах отработать час.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть предложение использовать ректальные датчики и CRM-систему для слежения за ними. Как известно, когда программист работает над кодом, у него неизбежно немного «пригорает», потому при правильной настройке системы (скажем, 3 пригорания в час), можно будет определить действительно ли программист работал или же прохлаждался за чаем с печеньем и обдумыванием путей возможного решения задачи.

Ну а если серьезно, то лучше такую задачу решать рыночными инструментами: диверсификацией разработчиков, мотивацией работать быстрее, введением KPI и прочими.

Answer (score 1):

Время работы можно трекать софтом. Я использую в работе [TopTracker](https://www.toptal.com/tracker/). Заказчик в личном кабинете видит, сколько часов потрачено на его проект, на какие задачи. Плюс каждые несколько минут программа делает скриншот экрана и снимок с веб-камеры.

А в договоре прописать, что оплачиваются только часы, затреканные в софте и подкрепленные скриншотами и снимками с вебки.

Comment: Какая-то драконовская система выходит.